# Java Webservice URL in JSF

Tags: java, web-services, jsf

I created a JSF application which also offers some Webservices. The webservices are created via annotations.

Now I want to create a webserviceInfo.xhtml Page , where I get all the needed webservice Information.

When I go to the address **http://our.server.com/application/OurWebserviceName**, I get all the information needed to access the webservice (this info page is generated automatically by Glassfish ).

To include this page, I did the following in the webserviceInfo.xhtml:

```
 <iframe scrolling="automatic"  width="971" height="1000" src="#{myBean.generateUrlToWebservice()}/OurWebserviceName"/>
```

Where:

```
public String generateUrlToWebservice(){
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    String servername = fc.getExternalContext().getRequestServerName();
    String port = String.valueOf(fc.getExternalContext().getRequestServerPort());
    String appname = fc.getExternalContext().getRequestContextPath();
    return "http://"+servername+":"+port+appname;
}
```

Is there a more elegant solution to this?

BR, Rene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a page-relative URL.

```
<iframe src="OurWebserviceName"></iframe>
```

Or make use of `<base>` tag with little help of JSTL `functions` taglib.

```
<html xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions">
...
<base href="#{fn:replace(request.requestURL, request.requestURI, '')}#{request.contextPath}"></base>
```

This way any URL which doesn't start with scheme or `/` is always relative to this URL.

Or if you *really* need to do it in JSF the following gives less headache with scheme and port.

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) externalContext.getRequest();
return request.getRequestURL().toString().replace(request.getRequestURI, "") + request.getContextPath();
```

Comment: Thanks, that solution with the relative path works perfectly. A shame that I didn't get that simple solution

Answer (score 1):

Better will be if you gets all parameters dynamically like protocol (http,https..) and pages (after app name)

```
public String generateUrlToWebservice(){
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext exContext = fc.getExternalContext();
    String servername = exContext.getRequestServerName();
    String port = String.valueOf(exContext.getRequestServerPort());
    String appname = exContext.getRequestContextPath();
    String protocol = exContext.getRequestScheme();
    String pagePath = exContext.getInitParameter("pagePath"); //read it from web.xml
    return protocol +"://"+servername+":"+port+appname+pagePath;
}
```